# Update QGIS Plugin from 2 to 3 ImportError cannot import name 'QPyNullVariant' from 'qgis.PyQt.QtCore'

Tags: pyqgis

I am recently working on updating an old Plugin for Version 3. I used the qgis2to3 in first place, changed the metadata.txt to qgisMinimumVersion=3.0.
The problem now is when running the Plugin this Error arises:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'QPyNullVariant' from 'qgis.PyQt.QtCore'**

When starting QGIS or activate the Plugin following error occures
[image]

here is part of the plugin code
[image]

I am using
Windows 10
QGIS 3.16 (OSGeo4w installation)
Python 39

Comment: `QPyNullVariant` is removed in PyQt5, try to replace it just by `QVariant` and in the code by `QVariant()`.

Comment: It looks like this solved the issue... makes me crazy I could not find this simple solution in advance! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QPyNullVariant` is removed in PyQt5, try to replace it just by `QVariant` in the import (`QtCore`) and in the code by `QVariant()`.

*Source* : https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html